# Probability of not picking yellow hockey ball when there are 6 balls.

Tags: probability

There are 6 hockey balls: 3 white, 2 yellow and 1 orange.
What is the P(not picking a yellow ball) when 3 balls are continuously picked?

How can you solve this problem easily with a method by NOT using the tree diagram which takes forever? Is there an easier way to solve this problem?

Comment: By "continuously picked," do you mean "picked without replacement"?  I.e., the three balls are necessarily distinct balls (possibly same color, but not the same exact ball).

Comment: yessir it means "Picked without replacement"

Comment: *Strategy*:  What is the probability that the first ball is not yellow?  Suppose you have picked a ball which is not yellow on the first draw.  What is the probability that the second ball is not yellow (how many of the remaining balls are not yellow)?  Suppose you have picked balls which are not yellow on each of the first two draws.  What is the probability that the third ball is not yellow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four balls that are not yellow, so there are $\pmatrix{ 4\\3 }$ successful ways of choosing the three balls.  There are a total of $\pmatrix{6\\3}$ ways of choosing three balls among all of them.

$$p=\frac{\pmatrix{ 4\\3 } }{\pmatrix{6\\3}   } = \frac{1}{5}.$$